# Every file in a specific folder always 777?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, chmod

I want to create a folder that is accessable via FTP on an Ubuntu Box. There are four users that are allowed to connect via FTP and I want them to be able to share files without restrictions. Is it possible to change every file to chmod 777 at the time of its creation? Thing is, that should only be possible at this specific location.

Thanks!

Comment: which ftp daemon are you using ?

Comment: I'm using proftpd. I could switch to vsftpd easily, if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With proFTPD the answer is that you can't set permissions to 777 it specifically does not allow files to be uploaded 777. You probably don't want the files to be executable anyway and  666 gives all the access required for an FTP server.

If you set the `Umask` directive in your `proftpd.conf` to `000 000` then all files will be created as `rw-rw-rw`and directories `rwxrwxrwx`

Answer (score 1):

The permissions bits on files created on *nix systems is controlled by the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).  Basically umask is a filter that tells it what not to set.  If you want 777 you need a umask of 000 which will not filter anything.

Since you are using proftpd, there is a howto that specifically talks about [setting the umask](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Umask.html).